# Inheritance in Hibernate Annotations?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, annotations

How can I configure Hibernate inheritance mappings using Java annotations? What are the advantages of using inheritance in Annotations?

Comment: Your question does not make too much sense. Can you provide more information about your problem?

Comment: @Zoman - if you're looking for how to use inhertience with annotations in hibernate, this question is just what you need. I just googled these three keywords, and got the answer here.

Answer (score 52):

3 possible types :

**1. Single table per class hierarchy strategy:**

```
 @Entity
 @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
 @DiscriminatorColumn(      name="planetype",
  discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING      )
 @DiscriminatorValue("Plane")
 public class Plane { ... }

 @Entity
 @DiscriminatorValue("A320")
 public class A320 extends Plane { ... }     


 <hibernate-mapping>
 <subclass name="DomesticCat" extends="Cat" discriminator-value="D">
      <property name="name" type="string"/>
 </subclass>
```

- Pros : Simplest. No JOINs required
- Cons : Cannot use nulls. # of  columns increase with the Object graph depth.

**2.    Joined subclass strategy:**

Database Tables

```
CREATE TABLE SUPER_TABLE(
id_col number primary key,
sup_Name varchar2(20));

CREATE TABLE  SUB_TABLE(
SUP_ID primary key,
sub_name varchar2(20),
constraint SUB_TABLE_fk foreign key (sup_Id)  references    super_table(id_col));


@Entity
@Table(name= "SUPER_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class TestSuperClass {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
        generator="SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name="SEQ_GEN",
        sequenceName="hibernate_sequence"
    )
    @Column(name ="id_col")
private long idcol;
@Column(name ="sup_name")
private String supName;


@Entity 
@Table(name="SUB_TABLE")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="SUP_ID")

<class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT">
<id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
...
<joined-subclass name="CreditCardPayment" table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
    <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
    <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
    ...
</joined-subclass>
<joined-subclass name="CashPayment" table="CASH_PAYMENT">
    <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
    ...
</joined-subclass>

public class TestSubClass extends TestSuperClass{ 
    private String sub_name; 
}
```

Test Module

```
TestSubClass sub = new TestSubClass("sub1");
sub.setSupName("supersuper"); session1.save(sub);
```

SQL Generated

```
 Hibernate: insert into SUPER_TABLE (sup_name, id_col) values (?, ?)    
 Hibernate: insert into SUB_TABLE (sub_name, SUP_ID) values (?, ?)
```

- Pros : Normalized data structures.
- Cons : JOINS are always reqd.

**3. Table per concrete class strategy:**

```
create table CREDIT_CARD( payment_id number primary key, amount
number, creditCardType varchar2(2) );


  @Entity
  @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
  public abstract class Payment {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
        generator="SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name="SEQ_GEN",
        sequenceName="hibernate_sequence"
    )
@Column(name = "payment_id")
private long id;

private double amount;



 @Entity
 @Table(name="CREDIT_CARD")
 public class CreditCardPayment extends Payment {
private String creditCardType;


 <class name="Payment">
<id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
    <generator class="sequence"/>
</id>
<property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
...
<union-subclass name="CreditCardPayment" table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
    <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
    ...
</union-subclass>
```

Test module

```
CreditCardPayment credit = new CreditCardPayment("C",1.0);
session1.save(credit);
```

SQL Generated

```
  Hibernate: insert into CREDIT_CARD (amount, creditCardType, payment_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

There's also a @MappedSuperClass  which we have used in our application.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very general question, but I'd advise taking a look at the following resources:

- [The documentation on how inheritance is declared via Hibernate annotations.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e829)
- [This PDF file](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/chapter2.pdf) (chapter 2 of a book on Hibernate).  Page 38 forwards deals with Hibernate annotations.

But the very basic answer to your question is that you should use the `@Inheritance` annotation, like so:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Flight implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes because I study to learn it. I'm stranger this subject. My onion is mix. So thank you for resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the @Inheritance annotation over the @MappedSuperclass.  We have had issues in the past with @MappedSuperclass being flexible enough for our ongoing maintenance needs.

Comment: Matt, could you please suggest what were the issues with MappedSuperClass, as we have used it extensively in our application.