# Hibernate mapping for superclass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have to perform **hibernate mapping** only by **using annotation** method in subclass according to following scenario in Spring MVC3 enviroment:

1) I have class called **Event.java** from xxxx.jar library with following properties

```
public Class Event{
   public integer id;
   public String start_date;
   public String start_date;
   public String text;
}
```

2) POJO class **CustomEvent.java** extending **Event.java** class using inheritance with following structure.

```
public class CustomEvent extends Event implements Serializable   {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String user;
    public String type;
    public String contact;
    public String status;
}
```

3) Im able to perform hibernate mapping using XML in following way

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="<package>.model.CustomEvent" table="events">
<id column="event_id" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property column="start_date" name="start_date" type="timestamp"/>
<property column="end_date" name="end_date" type="timestamp"/>
<property column="text" name="text" type="java.lang.String"/>
<property column="user" name="user" type="java.lang.String"/>
<property column="type" name="type" type="java.lang.String"/>
<property column="contact" name="contact" type="java.lang.String"/>
<property column="status" name="status" type="java.lang.String"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and its working fine.

Q) How I can achieve the same thing with JPA/Hibernate annotations?

I am new bay for Hibernate / Spring framework.

Note: Event class is present in .jar library, not able to see the code exactly

Comment: If it's new application consider to use annotations for mapping.

Comment: You can use mapped super classes http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12529264/892994

Comment: Thanks Erecan, in this approach super class should have annotated with @MappedSuperclass right?
If yes, in our case this super class is present in the ***.jar library, How we can give annotation for it?