# Exception querying inherited entities

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, persistence

In my db I have something similar:

```
+---------+
| answer  |
+---------+       ----------------------->--+--------------+
| id      +------)                          | answer_type_b|
                  ---->-+--------------+    +--------------+ 
  ...                   | answer_type_a|    | id           |
                        +--------------+    | field_b      |
                        | id           |    | ...          |
                        | field_a      |
                        | ...          |
```

In my `answer` table I have common information, then I have two inheriting tables related to the parent table and having different specific fields.

I created model in my application using JPA 2 + Hibernate 4.2.6:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class AnswerA extends Answer{

    @Column(name = "field_a")
    private String fieldA;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class AnswerB extends Answer{

    @Column(name = "field_b")
    private String fieldB;

    // ...
}
```

Now when I try to query all `Answer` entities I expect to get a collection with **ALL** the answers both Type A and Type B, instead I get an exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'answer0_.field_a' in 'field list'
```

I suppose this appens because there is no `field_a` field in parent table, so how can I solve this? Is there a way to query all the inheriting tables?

Comment: You should also post the variables of your classes and the SQL query with the surrounding code.

Comment: Since I am only forwarding you I post this as a comment: you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373294/inheritance-in-hibernate-annotations . I think the `@Inheritance(...)` annotation should solve your problem. (or just look up the hibernate docs, they are more up2date than the url I provided)

Comment: @Ben thank you very much. I find very useful also this docs http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved following [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) interesting wiki-book.