# Hibernate: Determining type column based on value of another column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, orm

In our Hibernate model of our database we have two kinds of users, standard and admin, each with a corresponding table (standard_user, admin_user). When an entity is modified we save which user made the last change on the modified record. This is done through two columns, user_type and user_id. user_types 1 and 2 refer to the standard_user table and user_type 3 refers to the admin_user table. So, for example, user_type=3 and user_id=2 would refer to the record with id=2 in the admin_user table and user_type=1 and user_id=2 would refer to id=2 in the standard_user table.

I would like to model this so that on any entity with this relationship there would be a field of type User which could either be a StandardUser or an AdminUser based on the value of user_type. I'm at a bit of a loss though as I'm not sure how to do this. Discrimator Values seem like they might be helpful but they only seem to apply to an entity, not columns within an entity.

Examples to help illustrate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "standard_user")
public class StandardUser implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer userId;
    private Integer userTypeId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_type", nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserTypeId() {
        return userTypeId;
    }

    public void setUserTypeId(Integer userTypeId) {
        this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "admin_user")
public class AdminUser implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer userId;
    private Integer userTypeId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_type", nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserTypeId() {
        return userTypeId;
    }

    public void setUserTypeId(Integer userTypeId) {
        this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer storeId;
    private Integer modifiedByUserTypeId;
    private int modifiedBy;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "storeId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getStoreId() {
        return this.storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(Integer storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "modifiedByUserTypeId", nullable = false)
    public Integer getModifiedByUserTypeId() {
        return modifiedByUserTypeId;
    }

    public void setModifiedByUserTypeId(Integer modifiedByUserTypeId) {
        this.modifiedByUserTypeId = modifiedByUserTypeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "modifiedBy", nullable = false)
    public int getModifiedBy() {
        return this.modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(int modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }
}
```

The Store entity shows how we record which user last edited an entity.

How would I go about mapping this relationship?

Comment: 1) Is this the model you guys are already using in production? 2) Why is it that user_type 1 & 2 (basically 2 values) are used to make it a normal user ?

Comment: @SahilGupta,1) We are currently using it in production, currently out Hibernate entities simply have the user_id and user_type as ints. We then have a service which uses these two values to fetch the user from the appropriate table (each table has its own entity, StandardUser and AdminUser). 2) We have another table called user_type which maps 1 and 2 to standard and power users respectively and 3 to admin users.

Comment: I should also note that we're aware that this is terrible :-) We do have plans in the future to combine both tables into a single user table.

Comment: Can you add sample entities in the question to make the question more clear to others as well

Comment: Why don't you just use multi-table inheritance functionality provided by hibernate ?

Comment: So would that be like the third example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529264/2767271)?